# Filtering Pandas dataframe and overwriting does not alter the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to perform the same operations (filtering) on two dataframes, but for some reason, the dataframes are not changed. I suspect this has to do with the view vs copy of a dataframe issue, but I was unable to find an answer which worked to fix it.

Here is a simplified code reproducing the issue:

```
In [1]:
  import pandas as pd
  df1 = pd.DataFrame(data = [(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,'a',9)], columns = ['a','b','c'])
  df2 = pd.DataFrame(data = [(1,2,3),(4,'a',6),(7,8,9)], columns = ['a','b','c'])
  dataframes  = [df1, df2]

  for df in dataframes:
    df = df[(df.b != 'a') & (df.c > 5)]
    print df

Out[1]:
     a  b  c
  1  4  5  6

     a  b  c
  2  7  8  9

In [2]:
  for df in dataframes:
    print df

Out[2]:
    a  b  c
  0  1  2  3
  1  4  5  6
  2  7  a  9

     a  b  c
  0  1  2  3
  1  4  a  6
  2  7  8  9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python [variable names are bound to values](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html).
Assignment statements do not modify values, they rebind variable names to new values.

For example, when you use a `for-loop` like this:

```
for df in dataframes:
```

Python binds values from `dataframes` to the variable name `df` (a new value for each iteration of the loop).
The assignment

```
df = df[(df.b != 'a') & (df.c > 5)]
```

merely *rebinds* `df` to a new value. It has no effect on `dataframes`.

To change the value of `dataframes` you could use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to build a new list and assign `dataframes` to this new list:

```
dataframes = [df[(df.b != 'a') & (df.c > 5)] for df in dataframes]
```

---

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data = [(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,'a',9)], columns = ['a','b','c'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data = [(1,2,3),(4,'a',6),(7,8,9)], columns = ['a','b','c'])
dataframes  = [df1, df2]

dataframes = [df[(df.b != 'a') & (df.c > 5)] for df in dataframes]
for df in dataframes:
    print(df)
```

yields

```
   a  b  c
1  4  5  6
   a  b  c
2  7  8  9
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. The link to the names and values article is very helpful. Probably something I should have studied earlier :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `.loc` and **directly point your list item**s, otherwise the new dataframe values are binded with your `df` variable.

For instance

```
for k in range(0, len(dataframes)):
    dataframes[k] = dataframes[k].loc[(dataframes[k].b != 'a') & (dataframes[k].c > 5)]
    print dataframes[k] 

   a  b  c
1  4  5  6
   a  b  c
2  7  8  9
```

Which yields

```
for df in dataframes:
   print df

   a  b  c
1  4  5  6
   a  b  c
2  7  8  9
```

see [pandas docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html)

EDIT : better, use a list comprehension (see @unutbu answer)